# How to deny all access to /dev/sda?

Tags: permissions, devices

I would like even applications not to be able to access /dev/sda .

If possible, I would even like to disallow root applications from accessing it, but that is not as important.

Comment: In most (if not all) systems, processes *not* running as root (or perhaps as a member of some special group, *e.g.* `disks`) can’t access `/dev/sda` unless you change the device node ownership and/or permissions.

Comment: Note that if some partition on `/dev/sda` is mounted, then applications *will* be able to access `/dev/sda` (via the filesystem). If you want to prevent *that* as well, look at mount namespaces (or chroot).

Comment: @dirkt It is not mounted .

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you're running Linux, since the device name is probably different in other systems.

If your distribution is sane in any way, disk block devices like `/dev/sda` will be set up so that only `root` can access them. Debian/Ubuntu have the devices also readable and writable by group `disk`, but the group has no members unless manually added:

```
# ls -l /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 Jun 19 17:14 /dev/sda
```

As for preventing root access to the disks, that's not easily done with regular permissions since `root` overrides the permission bits and has access in any case. Even if you could do that (e.g. by removing the device nodes completely), it would break stuff like `blkid`, `fsck` and any tools started by `udev`. I would expect that to be a bad idea.